# Managing with objects inside of array React state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state

I am trying to manage objects inside of an array. So I have array `item` which has some objects.

```
state = {
    item: [
        {
            cls: 'powder',
            img: ariel_12,
            productName: 'Стиральный порошок Ariel 1,5 КГ',
            price: 200,
            heart: heart,
            qty: 1
        },
        {
            cls: 'powder',
            img: ariel_12,
            productName: 'Стиральный порошок Ariel 1,5 КГ',
            price: 200,
            heart: heart,
            qty: 1
        },
    ],
    loader: true
};
```

I added a method which changes the image on click, but it changes the image in all objects

```
likedBtn = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        item: prevState.item.map(
            obj => (obj.heart === heart ? Object.assign(obj, {heart: heartRed}): obj)
        )
    }));
    console.log('liked');
}
```

How can I assign that method to prevent acting on all the objects inside of an array?

```
<ProductsItems liked={this.likedBtn} addToCart={this.clickHandler} cls={item.cls} img={item.img} productName={item.productName} price={item.price} heart={item.heart} />
```

Sorry for such a dumb explanation but I hope you'll understand it. The heart is blue and it is red when clicked. That is all that I need but when I click only the one heart, all others change as well

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it

```
state = {
    item: [
        {
            cls: 'powder',
            img: ariel_12,
            productName: 'Стиральный порошок Ariel 1,5 КГ',
            price: 200,
            heart: heart,
            qty: 1
        },
        {
            cls: 'powder',
            img: ariel_12,
            productName: 'Стиральный порошок Ariel 1,5 КГ',
            price: 200,
            heart: heart,
            qty: 1
        },
    ],
    loader: true
};
```

```
render(){
  <div>
    {this.state.item.map( (obj,index) => {
      <div 
         key={index} 
         onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}
         liked={this.likedBtn}
         cls={obj.cls}
         img={obj.img}
         productName={obj.productName}
         price={obj.price}
         heart={obj.heart}
      >
        
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
}
```

```
handleClick = index => {
  this.setState( prevState => (prevState.item[index].heart = heartRed, prevState)
}
```